# How to change the border-top-color for apex:pageBlock in Salesforce

Tags: css, css-selectors, salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I have two `<apex:pageBlock>` section in my visual force page.

I have id mentioned for each of them.

I want to override the color of the top border which comes when we use `<apex:pageblock>`.

Please find attached the screenshot. I want the 2nd green color to be red whereas the 1st one to be green as it is.

How can I do that? Please suggest a suitable way.

[image: VF Page]

Comment: You will need to create a demo for us to check what rules are needed.

Comment: It is basically SalesForce specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    body .homeTab .bSubBlock, .homeTab .bPageBlock
    {
        border-top: 3px solid #e39321;
    }
</style>
```